# Mathematically Find Max Value without Conditional Comparison

Tags: math, conditional-statements, max, algebra, min

----------Updated ------------

codymanix and moonshadow have been a big help thus far. I was able to solve my problem using the equations and instead of using right shift I divided by 29. Because with 32bits signed 2^31 = overflows to 29. Which works!

Prototype in PHP

```
$r = $x - (($x - $y) & (($x - $y) / (29)));
```

Actual code for LEADS (you can only do one math function PER LINE!!! AHHHH!!!)

```
DERIVDE1 = IMAGE1 - IMAGE2;
DERIVED2 = DERIVED1 / 29;
DERIVED3 = DERIVED1 AND DERIVED2;
MAX = IMAGE1 - DERIVED3;
```

----------Original Question-----------
I don't think this is quite possible with my application's limitations but I figured it's worth a shot to ask.

I'll try to make this simple. I need to find the max values between two numbers without being able to use a IF or any conditional statement.

In order to find the the MAX values I can only perform the following functions

```
Divide, Multiply, Subtract, Add, NOT, AND ,OR
```

Let's say I have two numbers

```
A = 60;
B = 50;
```

Now if A is always greater than B it would be simple to find the max value

```
MAX = (A - B) + B;
ex. 
10 = (60 - 50)
10 + 50 = 60 = MAX
```

Problem is A is not always greater than B. I cannot perform ABS, MAX, MIN or conditional checks with the scripting applicaiton I am using.

Is there any way possible using the limited operation above to find a value VERY close to the max?

Comment: Can you use bitwise operations?

Comment: "Now if A is always greater than B it would be simple to find the max value" Ummm... A?

Comment: why somebody was giving this question -1? There is nothing wrong with the question. But Cnich you should tell which programming language you are using.

Comment: The only operations I can perform are (/, *, +, -, &, |, !) I cannot do bitwise shifts.

The example I gave were arbitrary numbers and variables. I will not know the values of the information, just the variable names of course.

I am using an undocumented custom scripting language which is used to work with weather data, in this case radar.

Comment: just curious: which type of purgatory are you in, for this situation? And can we imprison Bill Gates there?

Comment: @Cnich: are these integer operations? If so, division/multiplication by 2 to the x is the same thing as shifting left / right by 2 to the x. If not, what do & and | mean for you?

Comment: @moonshadow: I did forget that shift is */ by 2. So this is plausible

Comment: Do you have the source code of the scripting language? Maybe it's time to add some new features.. :-)

Comment: My range of possible values ever would be 0-100. or 0-7 bits

Comment: And this scripting language has arithmetic but not conditionals? Are you sure?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: Unfort not available to the scripter to add function

Comment: The code shown in the update is wildly incorrect.

Comment: @CodyN i have posted an answer please check if it helps you...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[finding the maximum of 2 variables:](http://guru.multimedia.cx/category/optimization/)

`max = a-((a-b)&((a-b)>>31))`

where >> is bitwise right-shift (also called SHR or ASR depeding on signedness).

Instead of 31 you use the number of bits your numbers have minus one.

Comment: +1 Note this is only for 32 bits. If the numbers are 8/16/64 bits - the "31" needs to be altered accordingly.

Comment: If you are not allowed to do shifts:
int max(int a, int b){
 int c = a - b;
 int d = c & 0x7000;
 int e = d * -1;
 int f = e + 1;
 int g = f & 0x1;
 return (g * a) | ((g*-1) * b);
}

I used different variables so you can see what happens at each step.

Comment: In C, sign extension is not required, IIRC, so your code may not work.  Also, to be more portable, replace 31 with sizeof(type)*8-1.

Comment: @codymanix: An undocumented scripting language used through a weather applications called LEADS.

Comment: right shift a negative number behaviour is implementation dependent, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857928/right-shifting-negative-numbers-in-c)

Answer (score 32):

I guess this one would be the most simplest if we manage to find difference between two numbers (only the magnitude not sign)

```
max = ((a+b)+|a-b|)/2;
```

where `|a-b|` is a magnitude of difference between `a` and `b`.

Comment: This answer was exceptionally helpful. It also led me to `min = ((a+b)-|a-b|)/2`. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

If you can't trust your environment to generate the appropriate branchless operations when they are available, see [this page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) for how to proceed. Note the restriction on input range; use a larger integer type for the operation if you cannot guarantee your inputs will fit.

Answer (score 5):

Solution without conditionals. Cast to uint then back to int to get abs.

```
int abs (a) { return (int)((unsigned int)a); }
int max (a, b) { return (a + b + abs(a - b)) / 2; }

int max3 (a, b, c) { return (max(max(a,b),c); }
```

Comment: In C, this `abs (a)` does not return the absolute value when `a < 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Using logical operations only, short circuit evaluation and assuming the C convention of rounding towards zero, it is possible to express this as:

```
int lt0(int x) {
    return x && (!!((x-1)/x));
}

int mymax(int a, int b) {
    return lt0(a-b)*b+lt0(b-a)*a;
}
```

The basic idea is to implement a comparison operator that will return 0 or 1. It's possible to do a similar trick if your scripting language follows the convention of rounding toward the floor value like python does.

Comment: I did try to implement this method and did not achieve desired results. This did help me figure out that my values are not being rounded down but unfort being converted to doubles. AHH!

Comment: It translates symmetric relative to zero  `(-c;c)` pair to asymmetric relative to zero pair `(1;0)` pair. This is done by implicit `if` embedded in rounding convention.

Comment: does not work when `a == b`

Answer (score 3):

```
function Min(x,y:integer):integer;
  Var
   d:integer;
   abs:integer;
 begin
  d:=x-y;
  abs:=d*(1-2*((3*d) div (3*d+1)));
  Result:=(x+y-abs) div 2;
 end;
```

Comment: what it this langage ? natural langage ?
beautiful you only use elementary operator

Comment: Years ago I have a calculator that allows storing simple formulas, but no conditionals or functions like abs or min/max. I wish I know this back then, so many possibilities.

Comment: @Et7f3XIV this looks like Pascal programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. I assume NOT, AND, and OR are bitwise? If so, there's going to be a bitwise expression to solve this. Note that A | B will give a number >= A and >= B. Perhaps there's a pruning method for selecting the number with the most bits.

To extend, we need the following to determine whether A (0) or B (1) is greater.

truth table:

```
0|0 = 0  
0|1 = 1
1|0 = 0
1|1 = 0

!A and B
```

therefore, will give the index of the greater bit. Ergo, compare each bit in both numbers, and when they are different, use the above expression (Not A And B) to determine which number was greater. Start from the most significant bit and proceed down both bytes. If you have no looping construct, manually compare each bit.

Implementing "when they are different":

(A != B) AND (my logic here)

Comment: Can't do this without shift (and knowing the size of type in bytes).

Comment: Yes you can. Just and with 2**bit_index to get your comparison numbers.

Comment: Remember that "shift" is just multiply/divide by 2.

Comment: iftrue, is there a way to implement "and when they are different" without a conditional?

Comment: but not if the shift involves the sign-bit which is the case in my proposal (>>31)

Answer (score 0):

try this, (but be aware for overflows) 
 (Code in C#)

```
    public static Int32 Maximum(params Int32[] values)
    {
        Int32 retVal = Int32.MinValue;
        foreach (Int32 i in values)
            retVal += (((i - retVal) >> 31) & (i - retVal));
        return retVal;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this as a series of arithmetic and bitwise operations, e.g.:

```
int myabs(const int& in) {
  const int tmp = in >> ((sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1);
  return tmp - (in ^ tmp(;
}

int mymax(int a, int b) {
    return ((a+b) + myabs(b-a)) / 2;
}
```

Comment: myabs(-6) and myabs(6) is giving -6. so it should be            return  (in ^ tmp) - tmp;

Answer (score 0):

```
//Assuming 32 bit integers 
int is_diff_positive(int num)
{
    ((num & 0x80000000) >> 31) ^ 1; // if diff positive ret 1 else 0
}
int sign(int x)
{
   return ((num & 0x80000000) >> 31);
}

int flip(int x)
{
   return x ^ 1;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
  int diff = a - b;

  int is_pos_a = sign(a);
  int is_pos_b = sign(b);

  int is_diff_positive = diff_positive(diff);
  int is_diff_neg = flip(is_diff_positive);

  // diff (a - b) will overflow / underflow if signs are opposite
  // ex: a = INT_MAX , b = -3 then a - b => INT_MAX - (-3) => INT_MAX + 3
  int can_overflow = is_pos_a ^ is_pos_b;
  int cannot_overflow = flip(can_overflow);
  int res = (cannot_overflow * ( (a * is_diff_positive) + (b * 
            is_diff_negative)) + (can_overflow * ( (a * is_pos_a) + (b * 
            is_pos_b)));

  return res;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation using only `+, -, *, %, /` operators

```
using static System.Console;

int Max(int a, int b) => (a + b + Abs(a - b)) / 2;
int Abs(int x) => x * ((2 * x + 1) % 2);

WriteLine(Max(-100, -2) == -2); // true
WriteLine(Max(2, -100) == 2);   // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with an expression:
`(( (a-b)-|a-b| ) / (2(a-b)) )*b + (( (b-a)-|b-a| )/(2(b-a)) )*a`
which is equal to a if a>b and is equal to b if b>a

when a>b:
`a-b>0,  a-b = |a-b|, (a-b)-|a-b| = 0`  so the coeficcient for b is 0

`b-a<0,  b-a = -|b-a|, (b-a)-|b-a| = 2(b-a)`
so the coeficcient for a is `2(b-a)/2(b-a)` which is 1
so it would ultimately return `0*b+1*a` if a is bigger and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

### Find MAX between n & m

```
MAX = ( (n/2) + (m/2) + ( ((n/2) - (m/2)) * ( (2*((n/2) - (m/2)) + 1) % 2) ) )
```

###### Using #define in c:

```
#define MAX(n, m) ( (n/2) + (m/2) + ( ((n/2) - (m/2)) * ( (2*((n/2) - (m/2)) + 1) % 2) ) )
```

###### or

```
#define ABS(n) ( n * ( (2*n + 1) % 2) )  // Calculates abs value of n
#define MAX(n, m) ( (n/2) + (m/2) + ABS((n/2) - (m/2)) )  // Finds max between n & m
#define MIN(n, m) ( (n/2) + (m/2) - ABS((n/2) - (m/2)) )  // Finds min between n & m
```

Answer (score -1):

please look at this program.. this might be the best answer till date on this page...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    a=3;
    b=5;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    b = (a+b)-(a=b); // this line is doing the reversal
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> If A is always greater than B .. [ we can use] .. `MAX = (A - B) + B;`

No need. Just use: `int maxA(int A, int B){ return A;}`

(1) If conditionals are allowed you do `max = a>b ? a : b`.

(2) Any other method either use a defined set of numbers or rely on the implicit conditional checks.

(2a) `max = a-((a-b)&((a-b)>>31))` this is neat, but it only works `if` you use 32 bit numbers. You can expand it arbitrary large number N, but the method will fail if you try to find max(N-1, N+1). This algorithm works for finite state automata, but not a Turing machine.

(2b) Magnitude `|a-b|` is a condition `|a-b| = a-b>0 a-b : b-a`

What about:
[image]

Square root is also a condition. Whenever `c>0` and `c^2 = d` we have second solution `-c`, because `(-c)^2 = (-1)^2*c^2 = 1*c^2 = d`. Square root returns the greatest in the pair. I comes with a build in `int max(int c1, int c2){return max(c1, c2);}`

Without comparison operator math is very symmetric as well as limited in power. Positive and negative numbers cannot be distinguished without `if` of some sort.

Comment: Actually, sqrt does not have a second solution, not for a particular input, sqrt is a function: https://brilliant.org/wiki/plus-or-minus-square-roots/

Answer (score -2):

It depends which language you're using, but the [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator) might be useful.

But then, if you can't perform conditional checks in your 'scripting application', you probably don't have the ternary operator.

Comment: I'm sure if they can't use if, they can't use ?: either

Comment: No conditional statements available in the language.

Comment: @Brian, that what I said, and got downvoted for it. Maybe conditional statements aren't allowed in answers, too.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float a = 101, b = 15;
            float max = (a + b) / 2 + ((a > b) ? a - b : b - a) / 2;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: The question asks for a solution **without Conditional Comparison**. The ? operator is a conditional comparison.

Answer (score -3):

```
#region GetMaximumNumber
/// <summary>
/// Provides method to get maximum values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="values">Integer array for getting maximum values.</param>
/// <returns>Maximum number from an array.</returns>
private int GetMaximumNumber(params int[] values)
{
  // Declare to store the maximum number.
  int maximumNumber = 0;
  try
  {
    // Check that array is not null and array has an elements.
    if (values != null &&
        values.Length > 0)
    {
      // Sort the array in ascending order for getting maximum value.
      Array.Sort(values);

      // Get the last value from an array which is always maximum.
      maximumNumber = values[values.Length - 1];
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  return maximumNumber;
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Absolutely irrelevant and for max number in array inefficient.