# Output of a << with -ve no?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left shifting with a negative shift count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945703/left-shifting-with-a-negative-shift-count)

Consider my code follows

```
int main()
{
    int k=1;
    k=k<<-1;
    printf("%d",k);
}
```

o/p

> -2147483648

Why the output is like this.I know negative no's are stored in `2's complement` but here is there any use of this concept of -2s complement.Kindly give me some idea.

Comment: what do you expect? you are shifting with a negative index, not really sense

Comment: That can't be your complete code. For one you don't actually store the result of the expression `k<<-1` anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`k << -1;  // Before the OP edit`

and

`k = k<<-1;`

These statements are undefined behavior in C.

Using a negative value in the right operand of the bitwise left or right shift operator is undefined behavior in C (see C99, 6.5.7).

Comment: Thanks for answer ,Is the standard says this.

Comment: @pradipta See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945703/left-shifting-with-a-negative-shift-count for a cite from Standard

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the -2147483648 result - if you're testing this on an x86 processor - is that the shift count gets clamped to 31 (see "Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference"). So you're getting 1<<31, which equals 0x80000000, which when printed as a signed 32-bit integer becomes -2147483648.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but how -1 is becoming 31 here.

Comment: -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF (32-bit). So if you do a bitwise AND between -1 and 31 you get 31.

Comment: Thanks but how it is getting AND with 31.

Comment: That's the fastest way of clamping the value to 31; only use the lower 5 bits. As Intel's manual states: "The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31.".

Answer (score 1):

The result of a shift operation is undefined if the second operand is negative.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f96c63ed%28v=vs.80%29.aspx 
[Why am I getting strange results bit-shifting by a negative value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881455/why-am-i-getting-strange-results-bit-shifting-by-a-negative-value)