# Explanation of a method of counting set bits in a 32-bit integer

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

looking in the methods of counting set bits in this [link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable),  I found the following method

The author says:

> The best method for counting bits in a 32-bit integer v is the
>   following:

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                    // reuse input as temporary
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);     // temp
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24; // count
```

> The best bit counting method takes only 12 operations, which is the
>   same as the lookup-table method, but avoids the memory and potential
>   cache misses of a table. It is a hybrid between the purely parallel
>   method above and the earlier methods using multiplies (in the section
>   on counting bits with 64-bit instructions), though it doesn't use
>   64-bit instructions. The counts of bits set in the bytes is done in
>   parallel, and the sum total of the bits set in the bytes is computed
>   by multiplying by 0x1010101 and shifting right 24 bits.

Any explaination how this method count set bits?

Comment: Do it on paper by hand to see what's going on.

Comment: The first line stores the number of set bits in each pair of bits in the pair. The second adds the counts of two adjacent bit-pairs and stores it in the nibble composed of the two pairs. The third adds the counts of the two nibbles making up a byte, and then sums the counts in all four bytes; the multiplication with `0x1010101` moves the contents of each byte to the most significant and causes the addition.

Comment: A book called <<hacker's.delight>> has more details.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze example of questions asking for bitwise operation explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816927/bit-manipulation-clearing-range-of-bits/15817020#15817020  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547087/extracting-bits-with-a-single-multiplication  and there is more

Comment: I think this algorithm is mostly superior because it is so obtuse that you are guaranteed to look smart if you use it somewhere with no explanation...

Comment: This algorithm is only "the best" if you, on average, have many bits set in the word. If you often have very few bits set, other algorithms can take much less that 12 ops. See [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer?rq=1)

Comment: From Bo's link, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11816547/1711796) briefly explains something that looks very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because you can count the total number of set bits by dividing in two halves, counting the number of set bits in both halves and then adding them up. Also know as `Divide and Conquer` paradigm. Let's get into detail..

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
```

The number of bits in two bits can be `0b00`, `0b01` or `0b10`. Lets try to work this out on 2 bits..

```
 ---------------------------------------------
 |   v    |   (v >> 1) & 0b1010   |   v - x   |
 ---------------------------------------------
   0b00           0b00               0b00   
   0b01           0b00               0b01     
   0b10           0b01               0b01
   0b11           0b01               0b10
```

This is what was required, the last column shows the count of set bits in every two bit pair. If the two bit number is `>= 2 (0b10)` then `and` produces `0b01`, else it produces `0b00`.

```
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
```

This statement should be easy to understand. After the first operation we have the count of set bits in every two bits, now we sum up that count in every 4 bits.

```
v & 0b11001100         //masks out even two bits
(v >> 2) & 0b11001100  // masks out odd two bits
```

We then sum up the above result, giving us the total count of set bits in 4 bits.The last statement is the most tricky.

```
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
```

Let's break it further..

```
v + (v >> 4)
```

Its similar to second statement, we are counting the set bits in groups of 4 instead. We know, because of our previous operations, that every nibble has the count of set bits in it. Lets look an example, suppose we have the byte `0b01000010`. It means the first nibble has 4bits set and the second one has 2bits set. Now we add those nibbles together.

```
0b01000010 + 0b01000000
```

It gives us the count of set bits in a byte, in the first nibble `0b01100010` and therefore we mask the last four bytes of all the bytes in the number(discarding them).

```
0b01100010 & 0xF0 = 0b01100000
```

Now every byte has the count of set bits in it. We need to add them up all together. The trick is to multiply the result by `0b10101010` which has an interesting property. If our number has four bytes, `A B C D`, it will result in a new number with these bytes `A+B+C+D B+C+D C+D D`. A 4 byte number can have maximum of 32 bits set, which can be represented as `0b00100000`.

All we need now is the first byte which has the sum of all set bits in all the bytes, and we get it by  `>> 24`. This algorithm was designed for `32 bit` word but can be easily modified for `64 bit` word.

Comment: Good answer well explained Thank you

Comment: You should add this answer to the still open question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer .  It is really much better than most of the answers there as well.

Comment: @BaileyS- I'll add it there. Thank you! :)