# Difference between '(unsigned)1' and '(unsigned)~0'

Tags: c, operators, bitwise-operators

What is the difference between `(unsigned)~0` and `(unsigned)1`. Why is `unsigned` of `~0` is `-1` and `unsigned` of `1` is  `1`? Does it have something to do with the way unsigned numbers are stored in the memory. Why does an unsigned number give a signed result. It didn't give any overflow error either. I am using  `GCC` compiler:

```
#include<sdio.h>
main()
{
 unsigned int x=(unsigned)~0; 
 unsigned int y=(unsigned)1; 
 printf("%d\n",x); //prints -1
 printf("%d\n",y); //prints 1
}
```

Comment: Not behavior of `~0` is implementation dependent read: [Calculating Ranges of Data Types in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796041/calculating-ranges-of-data-types-in-c/17796122#17796122)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `%d` is a signed int specifier. Use `%u`.

which prints `4294967295` on my machine.

As others mentioned, if you interpret the highest unsigned value as signed, you get -1, see the wikipedia entry for [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement).

Comment: because the operator inverts *all* the bits.

Comment: `~` is a bitwise not operator, and flips all the bits.  Maybe you're thinking of `!` (logical not) which would probably give you 1 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your system uses [*two's complement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of negative numbers. In this representation a binary number composed of all ones represent the biggest negative number `-1`.

Since inverting all bits of a zero gives you a number composed of all ones, you get `-1` when you *re-interpret* the number as a signed number by printing it with a `%d` which expects a *signed* number, not an unsigned one.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your use of printf you are telling it to print the number as signed ("%d") instead of unsigned ("%u").

Second, you are right in that it has "something to do with the way numbers are stored in memory". An int (signed or unsigned) is not a single bit on your computer, but a collection of k bits. The exact value of k depends on the specifics of your computer architecture, but most likely you have k=32.

For the sake of succinctness, lets assume your ints are 8 bits long, so k=8 (this is most certainly not the case, unless you are working on a very limited embedded system,). In that case (int)0 is actually 00000000, and (int)~0  (which negates all the bits) is 11111111.

Finally, in two's complement (which is the most common binary representation of signed numbers), 11111111 is actually -1. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement for a description of two's complement.

If you changed your print to use "%u", then it will print a positive integer that represents (2^k-1) where k is the number of bits in an integer (so probably it will print 4294967295).

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` only knows what type of variable you passed it by what format specifiers you used in your format string.  So what's happening here is that you're printing `x` and `y` as *signed* integers, because you used `%d` in your format string.  Try `%u` instead, and you'll get a result more in line with what you're probably expecting.