# Type casting ~0 to (unsigned int) and (unsigned short) with format specifier %d and %u produces same result for short but different result for int

Tags: c, casting, bitwise-operators, twos-complement, ones-complement

On my way to computing ranges of char, short, int, and long variables, both signed and unsigned, I took help of the following solutions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085193/11320006
2. http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/Ex_2.1_cal_limits.html

According to solution 1, I expected `(unsigned short)~0` in the code below to output -1 and 65535, assuming its behaviour is the same as `(unsigned int)~0` code for the two format specifiers.

```
// the two statements below produce different results
printf("Value of unsigned int is %d\n", (unsigned int)~0); // outputs -1                                                                                                                                                     
printf("Value of unsigned int is %u\n", (unsigned int)~0); // outputs 4294967295

// whereas, the two statements below produce the same result. Why?
printf("Value of short unsigned int is %d\n", (unsigned short)~0); // outputs 65535, expected -1
printf("Value short unsigned int is %u\n", (unsigned short)~0); // outputs 65535
```

Why is there a difference in the behaviour of `(unsigned short)~0` and `(unsigned int)~0`?

Comment: Something to do with variadic arguments 'expanding'. So it'd be like `(int)(unsigned short)~0`.

Comment: `65535` can be held by `int`, but `4294967295` cannot.

Comment: `%d` is for `int`. It will treat whatever value passed as an `int`. Mismatching format specifier and argument (like passing an `unsigned int` for `%d`) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Arguments to vararg functions undergoes [default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions). This means any integer value smaller than `int` (signed or unsigned doesn't matter) will be [promoted to an `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

Comment: Widening integer casts are supposed to try and be value-preserving. That means that widening an unsigned will zero-extend it whereas widening a signed will sign-extend it. Converting to signeds when the convertee doesn't fit is implementation defined, but practically you can count on 2's complement reinterpretation. Mismatching format specifiers with the type of the corresponding argument is technically UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there a difference in the behaviour of `(unsigned short)~0` and `(unsigned int)~0`?

The behavior of those expressions is analogous.  Supposing two's complement representation of type `int`, each computes the largest representable value of its (unsigned) type.

However, variable arguments to a variadic function such as `printf` are subject to default argument promotions.  This affects `unsigned short`, promoting it to `int` if `int` can represent all `unsigned short` values, as is the case in your example (and to `unsigned int` otherwise).  It does not affect arguments of type `int` or `unsigned int`, or wider integer types.

The key problem with the code presented is that ...

> ```
> printf("Value of unsigned int is %d\n", (unsigned int)~0);
> ```

... exhibits undefined behavior on account of the `%d` directive not being correctly type matched to the corresponding argument.  `%d` must be matched to a *signed* `int`, but you have associated it with an `unsigned int`.  In practice, the UB is manifesting as interpreting the bit pattern of the argument as if it were a `signed` `int` instead of an unsigned one, but in principle, the program could have done anything at all within its power.

Note well that this also has undefined behavior because of type mismatch:

> ```
> printf("Value short unsigned int is %u\n", (unsigned short)~0);
> ```

The directive `%hu` would be the best match to the corresponding actual argument, but `%d` is acceptable because of the aforementioned automatic type promotion.  *`%u` does not match*.  In this case, however, the UB manifested is identical to the behavior you expected -- at least as far as the output indicates.  In practice, the bit pattern of the non-negative `signed int` argument has been interpreted as an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - because you are using wrong printf formats.

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Value of short unsigned int is %hd\n", (unsigned short)~0); 
    printf("Value short unsigned int is %hu\n", (unsigned short)~0); 

    printf("Value of short unsigned int is %hhd\n", (unsigned char)~0); 
    printf("Value short unsigned int is %hhu\n", (unsigned char)~0); 
}
```

**REMEMBER**

Always use the correct formats when using printf family functions!!!. Using the wrong ones may eve lead to the undefined behaviour

Comment: Doesn't `printf` ignore the `h` and `hh` length specifiers?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons does it answer your question? https://godbolt.org/z/4K1P76 Obviously it is not ignoring it

Comment: No, @ChristianGibbons, at least not in the sense that *the programmer* may ignore them.  The standard does not relieve programs from correctly type-matching `printf` arguments on width.  And it makes a difference in practice, compatibility-wise.  On the OP's platform, both `%d` and `%hu` are matched to the `unsigned short` argument, but on a platform where `int` and `short` are the same width, `%d` would not match, yet `%hu` still would.

Comment: Will format specifier "%hhd" work on all architectures or is it language guaranteed? In RISC-V 64-bits, I know it can be used, I am not very sure about MIPS.

Comment: @HasloVardos, the `hh` width prefix is standard since C99 for use with `signed char` and `unsigned char` arguments.  In particular, `%hhd` is an appropriate directive matching type `signed char` on any implementation conforming to C99 or later, architecture notwithstanding.

Comment: @P__J__ I believe that example invokes undefined behavior as you have conversion specifiers that do not match the argument (see C11 draft 7.21.6.1 p9).  That said, consulting the standard, I will concede that it *does* convert the value before printing with those length modifiers.  I must have been thrown off since the argument values will implicitly promote to `int` anyways, and the `PRIdN` types in `inttypes.h` that I've seen are defined without using the `h` and `hh` length modifiers.