# Largest positive value of a signed integer type of unknown size

Tags: c, signed-integer

If we have a unsigned integer type which we may not know the size of, for example `size_t`, then we can get the largest value it can hold relatively simply with something like:

```
size_t maximal = -1;
```

Is there a similar technique for a signed integer type, such as `ssize_t`?  As in:

```
ssize_t smaximal = ???;
```

Note, there may not be a corresponding unsigned type, for example `time_t` *(ignoring for the moment it might not even be integral)*.

**[EDIT 1]** The use of size_t/ssize_t/time_t are just for illustration purposes, I am looking for a general solution where there is no  XXX_MAX help.

**[EDIT 2]** This appears to work, but I am unsure if this is "just luck":

```
#include "foo_library_with_no_max_macros_because_they_are_dumb.h"

foo_int_type foo = (((unsigned)-1) >> 1);
```

(where the actual type of `foo_int_type` gets determined through some horrid pre-processor goop I do not wish to replicate)

Comment: @TonyTannous: What does that help?

Comment: What is `ssize_t`? This does not appear to be standard C.

Comment: @Walter: Correct, it is not standard C. It is POSIX, though.

Comment: As in `ssize_t read(int fd, ...)` -- it was merely an example type I thought would be reasonably recognizable as a signed type...

Comment: What is your **specific** problem? Looks like you ask about a problem which does not even exist. If you have an alias you should get the max/min value for, there should be an appropriate macro. If there is no such macro, you don't need it. Or the header with the alias is incomplete.

Comment: "Is there a similar technique for a signed integer type," --> For signed types: no.  For unsigned types: yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the size of the type and don't have library support to determine the maximum value, you can resort to exploiting the binary representation.

The usual way to represent signed integers is using [the Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The maximum value of a signed type in two's complement is a zero followed by ones (`011111...111`).

Now how to obtain that value? We need to start with a known value and use bitwise operations to obtain the desired result. Known values:

- 0 = `0000...000`
- 1 = `0000...001`
- etc.

don't really help. But

- -1 = `1111...111`

gets us rather close. Now we don't know the constant FOO_MIN == `1000...000` which we could use to `XOR()` with -1, so we can resort to bit shifting. If we shift `-1` right by one bit and ensure that `0` will be shifted in, we will get the desired value.

In C, right bit shifting of negative values is implementation-defined, so it can be both arithmetical (which shifts in `1`) and logical (which shifts in `0`) shift, and mostly it is arithmetical (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857965/5872193)), so we will need to type-cast the value to a large enough unsigned type before the shift.

Here goes:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "foo_library_with_no_max_macros_because_they_are_dumb.h"

foo_int_type foo = ((uint64_t)((foo_int_type)-1)) >> 1;
```

---

Alternatively, we can use `sizeof()` to produce `FOO_MIN`.

```
#include "foo_library_with_no_max_macros_because_they_are_dumb.h"

foo_int_type foo_min = ((foo_int_type)1) << (8 * sizeof(foo_min) - 1);
foo_int_type foo = ((foo_int_type)-1) ^ foo_min;
```

Comment: Would `uintmax_t` be preferable to `uint64_t`?

Comment: The usual way .... assuming a two's complement representation that doesn't employ padding bits.    Although, practically, most modern implementations use a two's complement representation, the standard doesn't require such a thing.   And your approach will not work for a different representation.   There are older implementations that use different representation of signed integer types, and no technical constraint preventing such a representation being used in future.

Comment: @Peter: All of the representations allowed by the standard have the same representation for non-negative integers. So `FOO_MAX` is always 011...11; the only problem is knowing how many bits there are without overflowing. Figuring out `FOO_MIN` is much more challenging precisely because it does depend on representation.

Comment: @rici - If you think that is true, provide a reference to section/paragraph in the standard to back it up.  Because I've seen that claim many times, but never seen any one provide a reference to the standard (even when asked) to back it up.

Comment: @Peter: 6.2.6.2/2: "There shall be exactly one sign bit... If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value." and "Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type". To interpret the latter sentence, see para 1 which defines the value bits in unsigned values: "If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and 2^N−1, so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to 2^N − 1 using a pure binary representation."

Comment: @Peter: As I said, 6.2.6.2 permits padding bits, so you don't know how many bits are possible. But if you knew that, you could construct FOO_MAX by adding successive powers of 2 (or or'ing them together), as long as you leave the sign bit 0.

Comment: @rici - that actually says that both signed and unsigned types have a set of value bits, and there is a correspondence between them.  It doesn't say they have to be laid out exactly the same (although it doesn't prevent that).

Comment: @peter: it says "the same value as the **same** bit" not "the same value as some bit". How can you interpret the use of the word "same" to mean anything other than "in the same position"?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the constants defined in `<limits.h>`:

```
#include <limits.h>

size_t maximal = SIZE_T_MAX;
ssize_t smaximal = SSIZE_MAX;
```

Comment: The use of size_t was just as an example.  Assume there is no manifest constant  XXX_MAX...

Comment: @JohnHascall: OK - you should probably add that information to your question to make it clearer what you're actually trying to achieve. Did you have any specific type in mind ?

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution, so no particular type in specific.

Comment: OK, but all the standard integer types have range constants in `<limits.h>`, so I'm not clear as to what kind of type you might be thinking of ?

Comment: @JohnHascall: There are no other types thatn the standard types, so there is always a macro with a constant. This for a good reason! You cannot define new types in C.

Comment: `time_t` is an opaque type - you have no way of even knowing whether it is signed or unsigned on any given platform.

Comment: @JohnHascall Yes, but `time_t` is defined to be an integer type in the standard headers.  For example, if I hover over `time_t` in Visual Studio I see the tooltip "`__time64_t`", and if I hover over the tooltip for *that*, then I see `long long`. There, we've reached a primitive type. Use `LLONG_MAX` in that case, or whatever is appropriate for your compiler.

Comment: This is starting to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you *really* trying to achieve ?

Comment: @JohnHascall: It would be `TIME_MAX`. But that is not necessarily an integer type.

Comment: @GovindParmar: That's a very bad approach. And where did you find `time_t` is guaranteed to be an integer type? (MSVC is a bad reference when it comes to standard compliance)

Comment: @Olaf it's true that `time_t` isn't guaranteed to be anything in the C standard, but `time_t` will also be a signed integral type on POSIX-compliant systems.

Comment: @GovindParmar: POSIX is not C! Most systems using C are **not** POSIX compliant!

Comment: There is a bunch of duplicates about `time_t` I am lazy to search for. But I remember the bottom line - there is *no portable way* of knowing it's limits.

Comment: My mistake for using time_t as an example... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy, fully portable way for signed types AFAIK.
You could put the `*_MAX` macros in a `_Generic` macro, and then you won't have to worry about them anymore.

```
#define Z_max(X) \
    _Generic(X,                                                                \
            char: CHAR_MAX,                                                    \
                                                                               \
            signed char: SCHAR_MAX,                                            \
            short: SHRT_MAX,                                                   \
            int: INT_MAX,                                                      \
            long: LONG_MAX,                                                    \
            long long: LLONG_MAX,                                              \
                                                                               \
            unsigned char: UCHAR_MAX,                                          \
            unsigned short : USHRT_MAX,                                        \
            unsigned int: UINT_MAX,                                            \
            unsigned long: ULONG_MAX,                                          \
            unsigned long long: ULLONG_MAX                                     \
        )                                                                      \

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",  Z_max(1)); //prints 2147483647 on my system
}
```

Comment: That might work, but `_Generic` has some compatibility issues with qualified types (there is a defect report). However, the question has an XY problem. As a sidenote: `_Geneirc is not a macro or a preprocessor operator! It is a normal expression.

Comment: @Olaf `_Generic` also has issues with duplicate labels so it might be difficult to portably fit stuff like `intmax_t` in there (because it's probably a `typedef` to `long long`). (Could be worked around with builtins such as `__typeof` and `__builtin_types_compatible_p`, which are fairly widespread.)

Comment: Yes, aliases are another issue (one cannot define new types in C). The report lists differences between gcc and clang afair. To me it looks like the whole thing was not well tought through.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an expression, but a function using a loop

```
#define integer int    /* change as required */
integer max()
{
  integer x=0x7f;
  size_t  n=sizeof(integer)-1;
  while(n--) {
    x <<= 8;           /* may create spurious warning for integer=signed char */
    x |= 0xff;
  }
  return x; 
}
```

or a macro

```
#define MaxSignedInteger(integer)                    \
  (integer)(sizeof(integer)==1? 0x7f :               \
            sizeof(integer)==2? 0x7fff :             \
            sizeof(integer)==4? 0x7fffffff :         \
                                0x7fffffffffffffffll)
```

Comment: This assumes 8-bit bytes and no padding; neither of those assumptions is portable.