# C: get the bits of an integer

Tags: c, binary, integer

I have a program that will take two 4-byte integers as input and I need to store these into integer arrays like so...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int vals1[32], vals2[32];
    int num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int num2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    // so argv[1] might be 47 and I would want to set the values of the vals1 array to reflect that in binary form
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hints: for a positive number, '% 2' extracts the least significant binary digit, and `/ 2` removes the final binary digit.

Comment: Your question is unclear. So is your input a string? Do you want to just store that as an int into an int array? Do you want a binary representation of your int? What representation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @Superlokkus, i am taking a cstring which i will cast to an integer using the atoi function. So, i start with "47" and turn it into the integer 47, but then want to extract the binary bits that represent 47 as an integer and store them in val1

Comment: `int nthbit(unsigned long long x, int n) { return (x >> n) & 1; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First task would be to convert a `char *` to an `int`, which you said you can. So here comes the next part i.e. getting the binary representation. For getting the binary representation of any data type, usage of **Shift Operator** is one of the best ways. And you can get it by performing shift on the data type and then performing **Bitwise AND** i.e. `&` with `1`. For example, if `n` is an integer

```
int n = 47;
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
   /* It's going to print the values of bits starting from least significant. */
   printf("Bit%d = %d\r\n", i, (unsigned int)((n >> i) & 1));
}
```

So, using shift operator, solution to your problem would be something like

```
void fun(int n1, int n2)
{
    int i, argv1[32], argv2[32];

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        argv1[i] = ((unsigned int)n1 >> i) & 1;
        argv2[i] = ((unsigned int)n2 >> i) & 1;
    }
}
```

You have to be careful about the bit order i.e. which bit are being stored at which of the array index.

Comment: `n1 >> i` has implementation defined behavior if `n1` is negative. You should use `(unsigned int)n1 >> i`

Comment: Like what exactly what happen if n1 is negative for example, please elaborate a bit more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mazhar [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857928/right-shifting-negative-numbers-in-c) explains it.

Comment: Depending on the architecture, the sign bit may be replicated or set to 0 or anything else might happen as long as it is specified for the target architecture. Just avoid right shifting signed integers that may have negative values.

Comment: Another point: you make the silent assumption that `sizeof(int) == 4` because you use `for (i = 0; i < (8 * sizeof(int)); i++)` and the sizes have a fixed size of `32`. Better write `for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)`

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the parentheses in the answer's code: `n1` must be cast before the `>>` operation.

Comment: Thanks for making it meaningful.