# what does "if(( number >> 1) <<1==number)" mean?

Tags: c

c program to check odd or even without using modulus operator

We can check a number is even or odd without using modulus and division operator in c program
The another method is using shift operators
number >> 1) <<1==number then it is even number,can someone explaain this?

Comment: Don't do that with a negative number - it is implementation defined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857928/right-shifting-negative-numbers-in-c

Comment: If it is a positive number then right shifting by one binary bit is the same as dividing by two (but it is an integer so there is no fractional part) and left shifting is the same as multiplying by two.  If you do an integer divide by two and then multiply by two the result will only equal the original number if it was even.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I'm not 100% on this, but I believe it doesn't matter how the implementation defines it, since they immediately shift it back to the left (whether it zero-fills or one-fills is irrelevant when the filled in bit is immediately discarded anyway).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Right-shift of a negative value is fully implementation-defined. The implementation could define it to be zero or `INT_MAX` or the integer nearest the square root of the absolute value of the operand. But even if the implementation merely defines it as an arithmetic shift, the subsequent left-shift of the negative value is completely undefined by the C standard.

Comment: Another way to check for and even number is `(number & 1) == 0`, or `!(number & 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unsigned number is odd if its lowest (1) bit is 1. What this does is shift right by 1, and then right by one, effictively zeroing out this first bit. If that bit was *already* a 0 (i.e. the number is even), then the number doesn't change and the == passes. If it was a *1* then its now a zero and the equality check fails.

A better, more obvious implementation of this logic would be:

```
if((number & 0x1) == 0)
```

which checks directly whether the bit is a 0 (i.e. the number is even)

Comment: `number & 0x1 == 0` does not work because `==` has higher precedence than binary `&`.

Answer (score 2):

A right shift by x is essentially a truncating division by 2<sup>x</sup>.

A left shift by x is essentially a multiplication by 2<sup>x</sup>.

6 ⇒ 3 ⇒ 6
7 ⇒ 3 ⇒ 6

If this produces the original number, it's even.

Answer (score 1):

> We can check a number is even or odd without using modulus and division operator in c program The another method is using shift operators number >> 1) <<1==number then it is even number

Do not use `if(( number >> 1) <<1==number)` as it risks [implementation defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480949/what-does-if-number-1-1-number-mean/73481604#comment129763355_73480949) when `number < 0`.

**Only for the pedantic**

This is likely **incorrect** on rare machines that use  [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) `int` encoding.

Of course such beast are so rare these days and the next version of C, [C2x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x), is expected to no longer support non-2's complement encoding.

**Alternative**

Instead code can use:

```
is_odd = number & 1LLU;
```

This will convert various possible integer types of `number` into `unsigned long long` and then perform a simple mask of the *least significant bit* (the one's place).  Even with negatives values in any encoding will convert *mathematically* to an *unsigned* value with the same even-ness.

**Modulus operator??**

> ... using modulus and division operator  ...

In C there is no operator defined as *modulus*.  There is `%`, which results in the *remainder*.
See [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

Right-shifting by one shifts off the low bit, left-shifting back restores the value without that low bit.

All odd numbers end in a low bit of `1`, which this removes, so the equality comparison only returns true for even numbers, where the removal and re-adding of the low `0` bit does not change the value.

Comment: Re “All odd numbers end in a low bit of `1`”: Excepting negative numbers in one’s complement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: True. I suppose I should say "on the vast majority of modern systems", not "all".