# Finding minimum in a very small array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, performance

I was working with long int data and I was trying to determine the smallest element in an array. I know the traditional way of looping through the array to find the minimum. This question is to check if there are other ways to speed it up.

There are some properties of this array which could probably help us speed up things, but I am not sure how.

The array has exactly 8 long int integers. Everytime we call the function, we find a min from the array and the number is replaced by another number and we repeat this step. (at least 8 billion times)

I was thinking of remembering the second largest number somehow for next iteration (Since we will have compared them in the current iteration). Would this be useful compared to the linear implementation of going through the array?

Also sorting is allowed, but we have to somehow remember the original positions using a temporary array. Would this be more effective.

Also is it somehow possible to use SIMD to determine minimum on long ints? Even a millisecond speedup is useful as I am doing this operation billions of times.

Comment: Is it right that *long int* is 32-bit integer?

Comment: @stgatilov this depends very much on the system used. Can be 32, 64 or even 128 bits

Comment: 8 elements is TOO few. It is important to know your inner-most loop completely in order to see how to vectorize it. Otherwise a vectorized version will spend all the time on various overhead of the outer code.

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of the new numbers? Are they uniformly random, is there a trend for them to increase/decrease or do they follow a specific distribution?

Comment: What's the purpose of this whole procedure? What's this eight-element array finally expected to contain? It's possible that a more aggressive optimization is available at higher level, possibly with a different data structure.

Comment: Its actually 8 different sorted data streams from different computers which I am funneling to create a complete sorted data set.

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg There are no patterns

Comment: **I smell premature optimisation**! So let me get this straight, you're going to transfer ~64GB (8000000000 * 8 bytes) over a network, and you're concerned that your CPU running this algorithm won't keep up? Coo-coo!

Comment: Yes, as it's a Gigabit connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this using SIMD, as you can parallelize up to 4 of the comparisons. The normal algorithm of looping through the array can't be vectorized because each comparison depends on the result of the comparison before it, e.g.

```
x = min(array[0], array[1])
x = min(x, array[2])
x = min(x, array[3))
...
```

If you change this to a kind of knock-out tournament approach, you can do several comparisons at once if you load values 0-3 into one vector and values 4-7 into another:

```
// these 4 ops can be done at once using SIMD
x[0] = min(array[0], array[4])
x[1] = min(array[1], array[5])
x[2] = min(array[2], array[6])
x[3] = min(array[3], array[7])

// so can these 2 ops:
y[0] = min(x[0], x[2])
y[1] = min(x[1], x[3])

z[0] = min(y[0], y[1])
```

This means that in theory only 3 vectorized comparisons need to be done.

In ARM NEON SIMD, for example, it would look something like this (comparing 8 32 bit values):

```
vldm     r1!, {d0-d3}
vmin.32  q0, q0, q1    // first vectorized comparison
vpmin.32 d0, d0, d1    // second comparison
vpmin.32 d0, d0, d1    // third comparison
// min value is now in d0[0]
```

In the last comparison you end up doing extra comparisons that you don't need to because it's vectorized, but it doesn't matter.

I've used ARM NEON as an example because I'm not really familiar with x86 SIMD, but the same approach should work and could be extended to 64-bit values, as in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795529/how-to-find-the-horizontal-maximum-in-a-256-bit-avx-vector)

As always, make sure you profile, don't optimize prematurely, yadda yadda yadda

Comment: I will try this idea out and will post back how effective it is.

Comment: I tried it out and it was not able to beat the sequential algorithm as avx2 has no support for 8 byte integers yet. Also noticed that gcc does try to do SSE by default (atleast it uses the xmm registers). Logically this is the fastest way for future avx-512 as there will be support for 8 byte integers (and probably a horizontal min-max function will also be available)

Answer (score 5):

The theoretical complexity of an algorithm with an 8 elements array is pretty much irrelevant. Searching linearly is very likely your best option, given cache locality and all.

Another option would be to sort the array in decreasing order once, and then simply replace the first element every time, and eventually shift the new number on the right.

In any case, try and profile.

Comment: If there is a trend for new numbers to increase. I would expect the bottle-neck in this approach to be the shift-operation (or reordering the elements if you like) a way to mitigate this would be to let the buffer be a circular buffer, so that you only have to shift the elements that are strictly larger than the newly inserted element.  (unless it is still the smallest ofc)

Comment: Wouldn't the shifting of two different arrays (one holding the numbers and other holding the original positions) be more expensive than simply looping through?

Comment: @chettyharish I never suggested that. "Shifting" here is the same as "shifting" in the implementation of insertion sort.

Comment: In addition to the 'complexity of algorithm is irrelevant, cache locality matters' part (which I very much agree with), I suggest considering to find the [minimum without using conditionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375882/mathematically-find-max-value-without-conditional-comparison). This is prone to over- and underflows, but chances are that you don't actually make use of the entire 2^64 range per integer, in which case it's ok and avoiding pipeline stalls might actually speed things up, too.

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg Actually, this is only a small part of a bigger picture that includes networking. This most certainly wouldn't be the bottleneck!

Comment: It is entirely possible that the stream might be slower than the min function (almost probable), but in cases where we end up selecting random elements and since all are from data streams, the throughput of streams is probably higher.

Answer (score 0):

You could organise the array in the form of a min-heap. Searching will be `O(1)`, and replacing will be `O(logn)`. This will better the time complexity from `O(n)` to `O(logn)`, which should be significant.

Comment: A small comment: There is no way to know for certain that there will be a speed-up in this case, as the size of the array is small and constant. It may be a speed-up, but you cannot know for sure unless you do some testing. I expect the heap operations needed to keep the heap sorted to be more expensive than simply looping through the array each time.

Comment: @StianV.Svedenborg: You have a point. I didn't think of it that way. I leave it to the OP to run the benchmark though. The heap may or may not help.

Comment: With such small values of N, asymptotic analysis is no longer relevant. You must keep an accurate accounting of all operations. In this case, brute force costs seven comparisons, while the heap reorganization costs one or two comparisons per level, and there are four levels; not counting the extra memory moves, nor the fact the branches are probably less predictable. I wouldn't be optimistic about a min-heap.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That is a good way of looking at it. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is just eight integers proceed as follows:

1. Sort the eight numbers the first time, keeping their original indices
2. Implement a **binary search in an "unrolled fashion"**: these are 8 if/else lines in your code
3. Use the binary search to find the largest number
4. Use the binary search to find the correct position for a new integer to insert

Comment: Using Binary search to find a place to insert does not seem like a viable option, cause you will have to shift a few elements to insert into an array. I might simply be faster to loop through the array. Again, only a benchmark can confirm what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-heap. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<int, 8> arr { 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 9, 2, 7 };
    make_heap(arr.begin(), arr.end(), greater<int>());
    pop_heap(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    cout << "Min Element: " << arr.back() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1
```

The naïve way here would be

```
*min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

or probably you could use a [`multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)

```
std::multiset<long int> ms { 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8, 2, 7 };

for every new_element
    ms.erase(ms.begin());    // ms.begin() is the iterator to min element
    ms.insert(new_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to get significant speedup on this operation given that N is so small, and the replacement process is inherently sequential. Though in theory a min-heap is the perfect tool, I wouldn't bet on it because of the overhead.

My suggestion would be to keep the array in increasing order and when replacing the minimum to use the insertion step of InsertionSort, i.e. shift the elements to front one by one until the insertion slot is found. You can unroll the code completely to avoid checking the end-of-array condition.

The benefit of keeping the elements sorted is that once you have found the insertion point you can stop searching. On average, you can expect an improvement on the side of the number of comparisons (but an increase in the number of memory moves :-( )

You can also think of a binary search to find the insertion point, taking 3 or 4 comparisons, but I doubt it will clearly beat a linear search.

---

If your values fit in a 16 bits unsigned integer, you'll be very happy with the `_mm_minpos_epu16` instruction.

---

In a completely paranoid version, you can avoid the unwanted memory moves by numbering the permutations that turn the raw array to a sorted sequence. There are 40320 of them in total (!). Arrange a gigantic hard-coded switch statement in which the linear search is performed in the relevant order given the permutation at hand; then replace the maximum and update the permutation index.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep a bit of information around and update it.

You have eight values x0 to x7.

Keep values a0 = max (x0, x1), a2 = max (x2, x3), a4 = max (x4, x5), a6 = max (x6, x7), plus remember which one was the largest of each pair.

Keep values b0 = max (a0, a2), b4 = max (a4, a6), and remember which one was the largest of each set.

Now getting the largest element is trivial. When you have it, and insert a new element, you need to update exactly one of the values a0, a2, a4 and a6, and exactly one of b0 and b4.

(Just noticed you were looking for the minimum - shouldn't make much difference).

Comment: Indeed, but that will take you some comparisons (certainly 2+1 to decide which values must be updated, and others) in addition to the updates. Not sure that the balance will be in favor of the min-heap approach.